# Is there a code analyzer for PL/pgSQL or PostgreSQL code quality check compatible with Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: postgresql

I am looking for a code analyzer or plugin to scan PL/pgSQL or PostgreSQL codebase for code quality check that I can integrate with Jenkins pipeline.

Does SonarQube has a code analyzer or plugin to scan PL/pgSQL or PostgreSQL codebase?

Comment: https://github.com/okbob/plpgsql_check can do a static analysis, I don't know however if and how that can be integrated with Jenkins